# Where is my Docker database that is used by the running application

Tags: sql, docker, docker-compose

I'm wresting with Docker for the first time.  I have use this [blog post](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/03/01/dealing-with-databases.aspx) to create a database in a Docker container for my ASP.NET Core 3 app, which is also deployed in a Docker container.

This is my docker-compose.yml setup:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    birder:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
    custdb:
       image: MyLocalRegistry:5000/custdb-image
       build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: BirderDBDocker.txt
```

This successfully enables me to build and run both the application and the database.  Here is the output of the `docker ps` command:

[image]

The app successfully connects and seems to add records to the database.  But where are they?  Can I connect to the data via SQL Server Management Studio?  Amd if so, how?

(I can connect SQL MS to the

> localhost, 1433

server, but the data from the running app are not stored on that server.)

Comment: Have you checked what’s inside the container? Try running `docker exec -ti <container id > /bin/bash` and inspecting the contents of the file system. Your database is probably there.

Comment: That command returns: `root@e0478c6276c7:/#`.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You are now inside the container. Try exploring its file system with `ls` and `cd` and see if you can find the database :)

Comment: Btw, if you have access to the Dockerfile describing the image you’re running, it can be useful to find out where the DB is stored.

Comment: The Dockerfile I used to run the db container is quite simple: `FROM MyLocalRegistry:5000/custdb-image`.  Just trying to work it out now..

Comment: And what about the Dockerfile of custdb-image. Do you have access to it?

Comment: I run `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 `
          --restart=always `
          --name MyLocalRegistry registry:2` and then `docker commit custdb MyLocalRegistry:5000/custdb-image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation of your image in https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server:

*You can connect to the SQL Server using the sqlcmd tool inside of the container by using the following command on the host:*

`docker exec -it <container_id|container_name> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password>`

*You can also use the tools in an entrypoint.sh script to do things like create databases or logins, attach databases, import data, or other setup tasks. See this example of using an entrypoint.sh script to create a database and schema and bcp in some data.
You can connect to the SQL Server instance in the container from outside the container by using various command line and GUI tools on the host or remote computers. See the [Connect and Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15) topic in the SQL Server on Linux documentation.*